# Scrapy doesn't retrive data to items from some pages

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I am trying to learn more advanced scrapy options, working with response.meta and parsing data from followed page. Written code does work, it visits all intended pages but does not **scrape** data from all of them.

I tried changing rules for following links inside of LinkExtractor and restricting xpaths to different areas of website, but this does not change behavior of scrapy. I also tried NOT to use regex `'r/'` but this doesn't change anything besides scrapy wandering off through out whole page.

EDIT: I think problem lies within `def category_page`, where i am doing `next_page` navigation in category page. If i remove this function and following of the links scrapy gets all results from page.

What i try to accomplish is:

1. Visit category page in `start_urls`
2. Extract all defined items from `/product/view` and `/pref_product/view` following from category page. Follow further from those to `/member/view`
3. Extract all defined items on `/member/view` page
4. Iterate further to `next_page` in category from `start_urls`

Scrapy does all of those things, but misses big part of data!

For example, sample of a log. None of those pages were **scraped**.

```
DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.go4worldbusiness.com/product/view/275725/car-elevator.html> (referer: https://www.go4worldbusiness.com/suppliers/elevators-escalators.html?region=worldwide&pg_suppliers=5)
DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.go4worldbusiness.com/product/view/239895/guide-roller.html> (referer: https://www.go4worldbusiness.com/suppliers/elevators-escalators.html?region=worldwide&pg_suppliers=5)
DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.go4worldbusiness.com/product/view/289815/elevator.html> (referer: https://www.go4worldbusiness.com/suppliers/elevators-escalators.html?region=worldwide&pg_suppliers=5)
```

Here is code i am using

```
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from urlparse import urljoin
from scrapy import Selector

from go4world.items import Go4WorldItem


class ElectronicsSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "m17"
    allowed_domains = ["go4worldbusiness.com"]
    start_urls = [
        'https://www.go4worldbusiness.com/suppliers/furniture-interior-decoration-furnishings.html?pg_suppliers=1',
        'https://www.go4worldbusiness.com/suppliers/agri-food-processing-machinery-equipment.html?pg_suppliers=1',
        'https://www.go4worldbusiness.com/suppliers/alcoholic-beverages-tobacco-related-products.html?pg_suppliers=1',
        'https://www.go4worldbusiness.com/suppliers/bar-accessories-and-related-products.html?pg_suppliers=1',
        'https://www.go4worldbusiness.com/suppliers/elevators-escalators.html?pg_suppliers=1' 
    ]

    rules = (
        Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=(r'/furniture-interior-decoration-furnishings.html?', 
                                  r'/furniture-interior-decoration-furnishings.html?',
                                  r'/agri-food-processing-machinery-equipment.html?',
                                  r'/alcoholic-beverages-tobacco-related-products.html?',
                                  r'/bar-accessories-and-related-products.html?',
                                  r'/elevators-escalators.html?'
        ), restrict_xpaths=('//div[4]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div/div[23]/ul'), ),
             callback="category_page",
             follow=True),
        Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=('/product/view/', '/pref_product/view/'), restrict_xpaths=('//div[4]/div[1]/..'), ),
             callback="parse_attr",
             follow=False),
        Rule(LinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths=('/div[4]/div[1]/..'), ),
             callback="category_page",
             follow=False),
         )

    BASE_URL = 'https://www.go4worldbusiness.com'

    def category_page(self,response):
         next_page = response.xpath('//div[4]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div/div[23]/ul/@href').extract()

         for item in self.parse_attr(response):
             yield item

         if next_page:
             path = next_page.extract_first()
             nextpage = response.urljoin(path)
             yield scrapy.Request(nextpage,callback=category_page)

    def parse_attr(self, response):
      for resource in response.xpath('//div[4]/div[1]/..'):
        item = Go4WorldItem()
        item['NameOfProduct'] = response.xpath('//div[4]/div[1]/div[1]/div/h1/text()').extract()
        item['NameOfCompany'] = response.xpath('//div[4]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/span/span/a/text()').extract()
        item['Country'] = response.xpath('//div[4]/div[1]/div[3]/div/div[1]/text()').extract()
        company_page = response.urljoin(resource.xpath('//div[4]/div[1]/div[4]/div/ul/li[1]/a/@href').extract_first())
        request = scrapy.Request(company_page, callback = self.company_data)
        request.meta['item'] = item
        yield request
        
    def company_data(self, response):
        item = response.meta['item']
        item['CompanyTags'] = response.xpath('//div[4]/div[1]/div[6]/div/div[1]/a/text()').extract()
        item['Contact'] = response.xpath('//div[4]/div[1]/div[5]/div/address/text()').extract()
        yield item
```

I want scrapy to grab data from all crawled links. I cannot understand where lies an error which stops scrapy from **scraping** from certain pages.

Comment: Have you tried adding [debug messages](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/debug.html) to your code, to try to find out where something unexpected happens?

Comment: It seems that the problem was in disallowing duplicate entries on website itself. Scrapy followed instructions correctly, it was website behavior which was a problem. Solution was to allow duplicate requests with ```dont_filter=True``` in request to  ```company_page```. If same company had multiple products scrapy was omitting those from items. This however is causing few more errors, but they are out of scope of this question. Thanks for a suggestion!

Comment: Please, consider writing a response to your own question based on your comment above.